# Script that allow me to export my Twitter stats periodically

Tags: linux, open-source, twitter

Looking for a (preferably Python) script that allows me to export and store my Twitter's stats periodically (I would create a cron task for the script to be executed every week).

The output format doesn't really matter to me, it could be just text files, it could be an SQL database,`.csv`... anything.